# Reference an item without displaying the text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference plain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54854/reference-plain-text)

I want to reference an item in a description, without actually displaying the text of the specific item.

I have a description with labeled items

```
\begin{description}
    \item[House\label{bld:house} is a building] \hfill \\
    A house is a building...
\end{description}
```

And I would want to use something like this

```
House\ref{bld:house} is something I don't own.
```

So that the output looks like this

```
House is something I don't own.
```

But instead I get this

```
House is a building is something I don't own.
```

So it references the whole text within the item. How would I just have a reference with my own individual text, like in HTML ([Google](http://google.com))?

And for some reason when I click on the reference it only jumps to the nearest section, but not exactly to the item.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think you are using the `hyperref` package to make hyperlinks in the pdf output? In that case, you can use the `\hyperref` command to make an HTML-style link to a label. As with HTML you need to specify what text is supposed to be clickable. Does the following code do what you intended? In my pdf viewer, `evince`, when I click on the word `House` it correctly jumps to the item in the description list.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[House\label{bld:house} is a building] \hfill \\
    A house is a building...
\end{description}
\hyperref[bld:house]{House} is something I don't own.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It "works" for me, in the sense that the output I get is:

```
House is something I don't own.
```

Since you didn't have hyperref in your example code, I didn't load it. Perhaps what you have is come conflict with hyperref?