# How to print something that in each section on the first page

Tags: cross-referencing, zref

I want to reference some numbers in each section on the first page of the document. But I can't find any package to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{zref}
\begin{document}          
\section{mytitleone}
%2 5 7 is supposed to be here by any amazing packages.


\section{mytitletwo}
2
something.
\section{mytitlethree}
5
Something.
\section{mytitlefour}
7
Something.
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Actually, I have a number in each section and I have to put those numbers in a table on the begin of the document.

Comment: @JouleV no. I want 2 5 7 to be printed there automaticlly.

Comment: Then what identifies 2, 5 and 7? Why not, for instance, 1, 6, or 10?

Comment: @JouleV this is done by my hand

Comment: @JouleV no rules for these nums

Comment: While \label normally saves the result of the last \refstepcounter, you can put pretty much anything into a custom version.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?r=SearchResults&s=1|31.9723#237126.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary anchors can be placed in a document with `hyperref`'s `hypertarget`,
and then referenced with `hyperlink` -- see [LaTeX/Hyperlinks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Hyperlink_and_Hypertarget).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}          
\section{mytitleone}%2 5 7 is supposed to be here by refference. 
\hypertarget{mytarget}{}% Empty target caption
\section{mytitletwo}
\hyperlink{mytarget}{2}
something.
\section{mytitlethree}
\hyperlink{mytarget}{5}
Something.
\section{mytitlefour}
\hyperlink{mytarget}{7}
Something.
\end{document}
```

Output (links shown with a red box):

[image: output]

Edit - After a comment exchange established that OP essentially wanted functionality provided by the label command in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54857/172926). I've added a variant of this command which doesn't print any text (see below). Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54857/172926
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mylabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  \label{#2}% Store label
}
\makeatother
% Example for OP
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l|l}
            Section & Reference\\\hline
            2& \ref*{section2number}\\
            3& \ref*{section3number}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\section{Second section}
\mylabel{3}{section3number}
\section{Third section}
\textlabel{7}{section2number}
\end{document}
```

`\mylabel{3}{name}` creates a label called `name` which provides a value of 3 (for example) when referenced. `\textlabel{7}{name}` functions in a similar way but also prints the value at the labels location.

Output:

[image: output 2]

Comment: I am not want to get a hyperlink here.

Comment: Right, I see the edit. You use the tabular environment for tables - see http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: but supposed you want to make a .cls file.

Comment: the problem is that I must put something you write which I don't know before it occur. It's not to have the table on the end of document.

Comment: Okay, so you're essentially are looking to do the reverse of what I did in my answer, but without the links? So you write '2' in section 2 and '2' appears in the table at the start? We can do that (let me know and I'll edit answer).

Comment: yes, please. The table is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

Using counters as suggested by John, you insert the number where you want and give a label to it with the command `\putctr{number}{label}` and then you refer to it using `\refctr{label}` passing the label you gave.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{myctr}
\newcommand{\putctr}[2]{%
  \setcounter{myctr}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{myctr}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{myctr}%
  \label{ctr:#2}%
  \themyctr
}
\newcommand{\refctr}[1]{\ref{ctr:#1}}
\begin{document}

refering the numbers: \refctr{A}, \refctr{B}, \refctr{C}

\section{title}
first use: \putctr{2}{A}

\section{title}
second use: \putctr{7}{B}

\section{title}
third use: \putctr{5}{C}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer due to John's comment and his answer of the linked ques.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\section{one}
\ref{mynum:1}
\ref{mynum:2}
\ref{mynum:3}
\mylabel{mynum:\thesection}{7} 
\section{two} 
\mylabel{mynum:\thesection}{19} 
\section{three} 
\mylabel{mynum:\thesection}{57}
\end{document}
```

Then we can use the package `interfaces-makecell` to generate the table automatically by `\repeatcell` and `\ref{mynum:\row}`. However, I use package `zref` to get the totoal sections.