# Referencing formatted text

Tags: cross-referencing

I am looking for an easy way to reference text I have in my document. Something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\labeltext[#1]#2{#2}

\begin{document}
Refer forward to (\ref{text:first}) and to (\ref{text:second}).

This is my \labeltext[text:first]{\textbf{First} item}.
This is my \labeltext[text:second]{\textit{Second} item}.

Refer back to (\ref{text:first}) and to (\ref{text:second}).

\end{document}
```

I want the output

> Refer forward to (**First** item) and to (*Second* item).
>
> This is my **First** item.
> This is my *Second* item.
>
> Refer back to (**First** item) and to (*Second* item).

Is there a way to achieve this? I would prefer to use the `\ref` command if possible (with the hope that other packages like `cleveref` and `hyperref` would work nicely with it) instead of creating a new custom referencing command.

EDIT: I found this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54857/93163) which works for plain text, but not for bold/italic text.

Comment: Yes, the text shouldn't contain any `\par`. `zref` looks to be what I need, though a bit complicated to figure out for this easy case.

Comment: I just wrote an answer where text can contain `\par`. I did not yet receive your comment about text not containing `\par` while writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) for implementing your own referencing-commands.

With the following example a few things are reimplemented in terns of `\long` so that referenecable text-snippets can consist of several small paragraphs as well.

However referenceable text-snippets are written to .aux-file as a single line of .tex-input. Thus the amount of referenceable text is limited by the amount of text which TeX can read from a single line of .tex-input. This in turn is platform-dependent.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user]{zref}

\makeatletter
% Implement some zref-infrastructure in terms of \long :
\@ifdefinable\zref@setcurrentlong{%
  \protected\long\def\zref@setcurrentlong#1#2{%
     \zref@propexists{#1}{\expandafter\def\csname Z@C@#1\endcsname{#2}}%
  }%
}%
\protected\long\def\zref@newlabel{%
  \@newl@bellong{Z@R}%
}%
\newcommand\@newl@bellong[3]{%
  \ifx\@newl@bel\@testdef\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \def\reserved@a{#3}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname #1@#2\endcsname\reserved@a\else\@tempswatrue\fi
  }{%
    {%
      \@ifundefined{#1@#2}\relax{%
        \gdef\@multiplelabels{\@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
        \@latex@warning@no@line {Label `#2' multiply defined}%
      }\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\def\ZREF@@@newprop#1{%
  \long\expandafter\gdef\csname Z@E@\ZREF@P\endcsname##1#1##2##3\ZREF@nil{##2}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\zref@newprop{MyCurrentText}{}%
\newcommand\MyTextref[1]{\zref[{MyCurrentText}]{#1}}%
\newcommand\MyLabeltext[2]{%
  \zref@setcurrentlong{MyCurrentText}{#2}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MyCurrentText}%
  \MyTextref{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Refer forward to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:first}{\textbf{First} item}.
This is my \MyLabeltext{text:second}{\textit{Second} item}.

Refer back to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Something with several paragraphs:

\medskip

Refer forward to \MyTextref{text:third}

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:third}{%
  \textbf{Third} item's first paragraph.\par
  \textbf{Third} item's second paragraph.\par
  \textbf{Third} item's third paragraph.%
}

Refer back to \MyTextref{text:third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If textphrases don't contain `\par` just do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user]{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{MyCurrentText}{}%
\newcommand\MyTextref[1]{\zref[{MyCurrentText}]{#1}}%
\newcommand\MyLabeltext[2]{%
  \zref@setcurrent{MyCurrentText}{#2}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MyCurrentText}%
  \MyTextref{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Refer forward to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:first}{\textbf{First} item}.
This is my \MyLabeltext{text:second}{\textit{Second} item}.

Refer back to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wish references to create hyperlinks to where the label was placed, you can try something like this—in order to see the scrolling-behavior after clicking a hyperlink view the resulting .pdf-file at a large zoom-factor:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[user]{zref}

\makeatletter
% Implement some zref-infrastructure in terms of \long :
\@ifdefinable\zref@setcurrentlong{%
  \protected\long\def\zref@setcurrentlong#1#2{%
     \zref@propexists{#1}{\expandafter\def\csname Z@C@#1\endcsname{#2}}%
  }%
}%
\protected\long\def\zref@newlabel{%
  \@newl@bellong{Z@R}%
}%
\newcommand\@newl@bellong[3]{%
  \ifx\@newl@bel\@testdef\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \def\reserved@a{#3}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname #1@#2\endcsname\reserved@a\else\@tempswatrue\fi
  }{%
    {%
      \@ifundefined{#1@#2}\relax{%
        \gdef\@multiplelabels{\@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
        \@latex@warning@no@line {Label `#2' multiply defined}%
      }\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\def\ZREF@@@newprop#1{%
  \long\expandafter\gdef\csname Z@E@\ZREF@P\endcsname##1#1##2##3\ZREF@nil{##2}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\zref@newprop{MyCurrentText}{}%
\newcommand\MyTextref{\@ifstar\MyTextrefnolink\MyTextreflink}%
\newcommand\MyTextreflink[1]{\hyperlink{MyText.#1}{\zref[{MyCurrentText}]{#1}}}%
\newcommand\MyTextrefnolink[1]{\zref[{MyCurrentText}]{#1}}%
\newcommand\MyLabeltext[2]{%
  \zref@setcurrentlong{MyCurrentText}{#2}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MyCurrentText}%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{MyText.#1}\hyper@anchorend}%
  \MyTextref*{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Links:

Refer forward to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

No links:

Refer forward to (\MyTextref*{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref*{text:second}).

\vfill

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:first}{\textbf{First} item}.

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:second}{\textit{Second} item}.

\vfill

Links:

Refer back to (\MyTextref{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref{text:second}).

No links:

Refer back to (\MyTextref*{text:first}) and to (\MyTextref*{text:second}).

\vfill

Something with several paragraphs:

\medskip

Links:

Refer forward to \MyTextref{text:third}

No links:

Refer forward to \MyTextref*{text:third}

\vfill

This is my \MyLabeltext{text:third}{%
  \textbf{Third} item's first paragraph.\par
  \textbf{Third} item's second paragraph.\par
  \textbf{Third} item's third paragraph.%
}

\vfill

Links:

Refer back to \MyTextref{text:third}

No links:

Refer back to \MyTextref*{text:third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Names of destinations within the .pdf-file are of pattern MyText.<referencing-label>.